# Dajax function unable to call another function

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, dajaxice, dajax

I have a `Song` model with a `votes` attribute. I have a `Vote as Favourite` button displayed below each `Song` object. I want when a user clicks on the `Vote as Favourite` button the `votes` attribute associated with that `Song` object should increment by 1 and all the `Vote as Favourite` buttons should be disabled.

**HTML**

```
{% for song in dj_song_list %}
    <div>
        <p><h3>{{ song.name }}</h3></p>
        <p class="song_id">{{ song.song_id }}</p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-custom" class='vote' onclick="update();">Vote as Favourite</button>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

**ajax.py**

```
def update_votes(id):
    song = Song.objects.get(song_id=id)
    song.votes += 1
    song.save()

@dajaxice_register
def update_disable(request, song_id):
    update_votes(song_id)
    dajax = Dajax()
    dajax.assign('.vote', 'disabled', 'disabled')
    return dajax.json()
```

**JavaScript**

```
function update(){
     Dajaxice.hunt.update_disable(Dajax.process,{'song_id':$('.song_id').val()})
}
```

The button disabling part works fine when used alone. But when I use the `update_votes()` function in the `update_disable()` function nothing works. What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had set the `votes` attribute of the `Song` model to `default=None`. Hence it wasn't able to perform the addition operation. I set it now as `default=0` instead.

Answer (score 1):

AJAX part does nothing, because it gets errors. The problem is in the `update_votes()` function. The problems could be:

- Several objects exist with same `song_id` value
- The song with `id` does not exist

Try using `pdb.set_trace()` for debugging purposes:

```
def update_votes(id):
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    song = Song.objects.get(song_id=id)
```

Comment: The id is a song id unique to each song that i'm getting from the Beatport API, it isn't the primary key.

Comment: Still, the problem is in this line. Check if song with ``song_id`` really exists.

Comment: My `Song` model has a `song_id` field.

Comment: Does your ``update_votes`` function get a valid ``id`` value?

Comment: But `song_id` isn't a unique field. I think that might be causing the problem. How can I get primary key associated with the Song object to send to the `update_votes()` function?

Comment: Simple solution: ``Song.objects.filter(song_id=id)[0].pk``.

Comment: This is what the traceback returns.
`c:\jaskaran\dropbox\edmhunters\hunt\ajax.py(7)update_votes()
song = Song.objects.filter(song_id=id)[0].pk`